# Determining the area inscribed into square

Tags: geometry

[image]

> From the statement i have got the area  of the square S is 10. Because
>   the square T is inscribed into the square S then why not 45 is the
>   smallest square for T?

Comment: Actually the area of $S$ is $100$ rather than $10$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather depends on what inscribed means, but it probably means that the vertices of $T$ lie on the edges of $S$, something like this.

[image]

$S$ is the outer square, while $T$ is the rotated square made up of a smaller square and four grey triangles.  Since the area of the grey triangles is equal to the area of the green triangles, you will minimise the area of $T$ if the innermost square has zero area.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The vertices of $T$ are on the sides of $S$, so the least possible value for the diagonal of $T$ is $10$ (the length of the sides of $S$).